# if e else com blocos quase iguais

Tags: python, python-3.x, condição

Em Python, suponha que eu tenha uma função:

```
def func(x):
    if x%2 == 0:
        j = x/2
        print(j)
    else:
        j = x
        print(j)
```

*Não se atente à lógica do código, é apenas um exemplo simples.*

Os blocos de if e else são quase idênticos. Existe alguma maneira de evitar essa repetição que, se frequente no código, pode torná-lo não-elegante? Algo do tipo:

```
def func(x):
   j = x/2, if x%2 == 0, else j=x
   print(j)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você quase acertou com seu exemplo. É o [operador ternário](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html):

```
def func(x):
    j = x/2 if x % 2 == 0 else x
    print(j)
```

Não é possível fazer um `elif`, mas é possível de ligar mais de um operador ternário em série.

```
for i in range(10):
    j = x/3 if x % 3 == 0 else x/2 if x % 2 == 0 else x
    print(j)
```

Eu realmente não recomendo fazer isso, porém; um operador ternário já prejudica um pouco a legibilidade do código se não é usado pra algo trivial. Com mais de um na mesma linha, o código rapidamente fica uma bagunça.

Comment: É possível um 'elif' em vez de else?

Comment: @WilliamLio veja a resposta editada!

Comment: na verdade, ao encadear o operador ternário "if " o legal é usar parenteses: a precedencia não é ambigua, mas a legibilidade fica melhorada.

Comment: @jsbueno dá pra fazer, mas o legal mesmo é não encadear!

Answer (score 2):

Poderia também retornar o valor em um caso , e caso ele não ocorra retornar o outro, funcionando como um "if/else" .

```
def func(x):
    if j % 2 == 0:
        return x/2
    return x
```

Answer (score 2):

Invés de atribuir o valor para J e depois exibi-lo, poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
def func(x):
    print(x/2 if x%2 == 0 else x)
```

Comment: Sim, o 'j' foi apenas para que os blocos tivessem mais de uma linha.